# How do I manage GitLab runner permissions at a larger scale?

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a group configuration similar to this:

```
root/
    sub1/
        sub1.1/
            sub1.1.1/
        sub1.2/
            sub1.2.1/
            sub1.2.2/
                ... you get the idea
    sub2/
        ...
    sub3/
        ...
    ...etc
```

We are in the process of cleaning up our GitLab instance and we are trying to fix our CI/CD performance.

Originally, all runners were shared between all projects, but we are now trying to assign runners to specific groups, with separate ownerships.
I, for example, have ownership over the `sub1` and `sub2` groups, but not `sub3`, and I do NOT want any of my runners to be used by `sub3` projects.

There are a **lot** of projects in each group (multiple 100s), with existing CI/CD pipelines (and common tags such as `docker` and `linux`), and I would like not to have to modify anything at the project level.

I would also like to have a single runner per machine, because I find it a lot easier to manage their configurations this way.

I am not sure what the best way to achieve this is, but from what I understand, I have the following options:

- Prefix all my tags with a unique id, e.g. `docker` becomes `my_docker`. This I want to avoid, as it would require modifying all existing projects.
- Create project runners instead of group runners. This would require manually adding the runner to *all* projects in the group, which is not feasible. This could be scripted, but c'mon, there has to be a better way.
- Create group runners at the subgroup level. This would mean that I use *different* runners even though the tags are the same, which is not ideal.

I am currently using the [ansible gitlab_runner module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gitlab_runner_module.html) to try to manage my runners `as-code`, but it is a bit limited from what I can see.